# Fetch request to Express server stall using PERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, fetch

When I make a fetch request from my react front-end (localhost:3000) to my Express back-end, my browser console advises "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" and the network tab of my developer tools advises the connection stalled.

I've done some troubleshooting with my back-end and the problem happens intermittently, only when I try to make a call to my database (postgreSQL). There are no errors logged or caught. the res.end() does not fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out after a day of trial and error and research. My nodemon was restarting my server between calls because some of my middleware was saving new files to my server. This meant the server restarted between sending/receiving calls to my database.

I resolved the issue by adding nodemonConfig to my package.json in order to ignore files and directories when triggering refreshes.